# How to destroy Fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I'm trying to destroy [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). I haven't found any method to do it in [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs). How to destroy it after it was initialized?

This doesn't work:

```
$("a").unbind('fancybox').unbind('click');
```

Testing code: http://jsfiddle.net/martinba/yy3cw/2/

I use current version 2.1.4.

Comment: What do you mean by destroy? Do you want to hide these all?

Comment: I need it back to standart behaviour: you click on the link <a href="..."> ... </a> and the browser will open it. No Fancybox inner windows, just like there's no javascript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to unbind fancybox you have to unbind events under `fb-start` namespace from `document`:

```
$(document).unbind('click.fb-start');
```

Though, I don't know why developer made it so unobvious.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/yy3cw/16/

Comment: If I have multiple fancybox instances on my page, like image gallery -
is there any way to unbind only specific images but not the whole thing?

Comment: @Passer by I suggest that you post a new answer with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call:

`.unbind('click.fb')` to unbind fancybox.

like:

```
$('.group').unbind('click.fb')
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/martinba/yy3cw/11/ Click on init button and then destroy. "FancyDevil" is still there.

Comment: This worked for me. The 'click.fb-start' didn't. I guess it depends on the FB version.

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind every fancy box by running:

```
$(document).unbind('click.fb-start');
```

Or if you need to unbind a specific selector, you can undelegate it:

```
var selector = 'a.my-fancy-box';
selector = selector + ":not('.fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav')";
$(document).undelegate(selector, 'click.fb-start');
```

Or alternatively:

```
// Bind
$('a.my-fancy-box').fancybox({live: false});

// Unbind
$('a.my-fancy-box').unbind('click.fb');
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned here earlier: `$(document).unbind('click.fb-start');`
But you also might want to add this option to the fancybox init call: `live:false`